# Setting on server to download a file instead of displaying it

Tags: html, apache-flex, http, web-applications, air

My server for some reason displays .AIR file inside the browser, but I want to have it downloaded. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server’s .htaccess (if it is an Apache) add the following line to trigger the download dialog:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .air
```

If you want the user’s browser let decide what to do, use the type @Mike has recommended:

```
AddType application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip .air
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `Content-Disposition` header of the HTTP response to `attachment`, if necessary along with a `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I think this is the best solution - 
Setting the correct MIME type:
http://blogs.adobe.com/ashutosh/2009/02/setting_the_correct_mime_type.html